# How to write int to file in MIPS?

Tags: list, mips, system-calls

I'm doing a homework where I have to read a non-fixed numbers of integers separated by \n from a text file and sort them in a linked list (and in an array, to compare performance). After that, I have to write the sorted list into another text file, and that's where my problem is. I don't really know how syscall 15 works (write to file). I don't know what kind of input it would print to the file. I mean, I'm guessing they have to be strings, not integers... so I made a little test program and it didn't work. Here it is:

```
.data   
    archivo: .asciiz "salida.txt"
.text
# reservar memoria para 3 chars + \0
li $v0, 9
li $a0, 4
syscall
move $s0, $v0
# agregar al array el numero 1 ascii
addi $t0, $zero, 49
sw $t0, 0($s0)
addi $s0, $s0, 4
# agregar al array el numero 0 ascii
addi $t0, $zero, 48
sw $t0, 0($s0)
addi $s0, $s0, 4
# agregar al array el numero 0 ascii
addi $t0, $zero, 48
sw $t0, 0($s0)
addi $s0, $s0, 4
# agregar al array \0 al final
addi $t0, $zero, 0
sw $t0, 0($s0)

addi $s0, $s0, -12

# abrir archivo en modo lectura
li $v0, 13
la $a0, archivo
li $a1, 1
li $a2, 0
move $s1, $v0
syscall
# escribir buffer $s0 en el archivo
li $v0, 15
move $a0, $s1
move $a1, $s0
addi $a2, $zero, 4
syscall
# cerrar archivo
li $v0, 16
move $a0, $s1
syscall
# finalizar ejecucion
li $v0, 17
syscall
```

I tried to allocate enough memory for 3 chars + \0 char, in order to write the number 100 to the file "salida.txt". So, I stored the ascii values of 1, 0, 0 into an array (which is the allocated memory), and then decrement the pointer, to point to the beginning of that memory block. After that, I open the file in write-mode and write 4 characters of the buffer $s0.
Unfortunately, this only creates the file but writes nothing in it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

---

I also tried writing a variable declared in .data, like this:

```
.data   
hola: .asciiz "hola"
.text
la $s3, hola
...
# do syscall 15 with move $a1, $s3
```

but this didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you need to store the numbers as bytes in the array you want to print. So, if you want to write a number, you store its ascii number as byte using "sb". I used a little example I found online and modified it to my testing needs. I stored a number backwards in an array and wrote that to a file.

```
    .data
fout:   .asciiz "testout.txt"      # filename for output
    .text
# allocate memory for 3 chars + \n, no need to worry about \0
li $v0, 9
li $a0, 4   # allocate 4 bytes for 4 chars
syscall
move $s0, $v0

addi $s0, $s0, 3    # point to the end of the buffer

li $t3, 10      # end line with \n
sb $t3, 0($s0)
addi $s0, $s0, -1
# start witing the number 100 backwars. ascii_to_dec(48) = 0, ascii_to_dec(49) = 1
li $t3, 48
sb $t3, 0($s0)
addi $s0, $s0, -1   # move the pointer backwards, meaning you go from the end to the beginning

li $t3, 48
sb $t3, 0($s0)
addi $s0, $s0, -1

li $t3, 49
sb $t3, 0($s0)

# Open (for writing) a file that does not exist
li   $v0, 13       # system call for open file
la   $a0, fout     # output file name
li   $a1, 1       # Open for writing (flags are 0: read, 1: write)
li   $a2, 0        # mode is ignored
syscall            # open a file (file descriptor returned in $v0)
move $s6, $v0      # save the file descriptor 

# Write to file just opened
li   $v0, 15       # system call for write to file
move $a0, $s6      # file descriptor 
move $a1, $s0      # address of buffer from which to write
li   $a2, 4        # hardcoded buffer length
syscall            # write to file

# Close the file 
li   $v0, 16       # system call for close file
move $a0, $s6      # file descriptor to close
syscall            # close file
```